# Does MySQL Cluster is compatible with PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql-cluster

I have a problem with MySQL Cluster and PhpMyAdmin, i'm not able to login in PhpMyAdmin when I start MySQL Cluster but I can when I just start MySQL. Someone has any idea how to solve my prob. Thanks

Comment: Any log entries? How have you set up the different MySQL Cluster node types? This question doesn't have the essential information in order for one to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Cluster, from a client/compatibility perspective, looks and functions just like plain MySQL. Something else is going on - you'll want to check that you've got the hostname, ports, etc. correct and that you can connect via the CLI.